# How to pronounce "undoes"?

Tags: verbs, pronunciation, conjugation, irregular, derivation

How should "undoes" be pronounced in the following sentence?

> The git revert command undoes a committed snapshot.

Should it be pronounced as "*un + does*" (`/ʌn'dʌz/`) or as "*undo + es*" (`ʌn'duːz`)? I think the latter one sounds fine here. But if pronouncing as `/ʌnˈduːz/` is fine, why is "does" not pronounced `/duːz/`?

Comment: Who says it should be ʌn'duːz? Never heard that.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That was just my guess. Turns out I was wrong!

Comment: do -> does, undo -> undoes.  Adding the "un" prefix does not significantly change the pronunciation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely /ʌn'dʌz/.
If you look at etymology, you see the archaic words for 'does' used to be 'doth' which is pronounced as /dʌθ/ and 'dost' /dʌst/ and such.