# How many verbs end with "-do"?

Tags: irregular

I'm searching the verb ends with "do".

I found out "undo","redo","overdo","underdo","outdo",and "do".

Are there other Verbs end with "-do"?

I think they follow the irregular conjugation like "-do".

Is there some exceptions of this rule?

Or did I find all range of "-do" Verbs?

Comment: Related: [How to pronounce “undoes”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358423)

Comment: How about "voodoo"?

Comment: @Hot Licks Voodoo is a noun. and it ends with "doo" not "do",so it is out of my wants.Thanks for your search.

Comment: @user9402680 - Actually, it can be a verb.

Comment: @Hot Licks really?I didn't know it was.But if it is so,it doesn't end with "-do."I'm sorry for that if you take "-do" for "-do.".

Answer (score 1):

How about updo (a style of hairdo)? I admit that claiming there's a verb behind that gerund may be shaky: the stylist updid my hair while it was still wet...(?!).

Comment: +1 yes,I didn't find it.Thank you very much.

Comment: Surprising to say,it is not in my Dictionary(paper & electoric).I have researched it on the web and certainly it is a kind of "[https://www.dictionary.com/browse/updo]verb",but there is no example of conjugation.It is well-known as a noun for hairstyle.

Comment: I think an *up**do*** is type of *hair**do***. It is a *hairdo* that is *up*, so it is no more a verb than *hairdo* is. I don't think I can be *\*hairdone* and I don't think my hair can be *\*updone*.

Answer (score 1):

[*Predone*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predone) exists and I would consider that part of a verb. Oxford Dictionaries says it is an adjective but it is a compound of *done* and that is part of a verb. I think they are only calling it an adjective because the rest of the verb does not exist. Any participle can be called an adjective if you want. If there are bits missing from a verb that does not mean it is not a verb; rather it means it is a [defective verb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb).

Comment: Yes,+1.It seems that only "predone" remained.I wonder if "predo" existed.Were other conjugations  exitinced...?